# How to disable the responsive temporary

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

How to disable the responsiveness / grid of bootstrap?

I am building the website for the company, and i already make the website responsive for the mobile devices. However, they told me they want to make another design for the mobile, but the desktop version will be published first. They want to keep desktop design when user using mobile or make the browser to mobile size, like traditional website, user should scroll left and right to view the website.

I've tried to add `min-width` on the wrapper/body, it just extend the width, but the elements using bootstrap grid still responsive. Can I using simple css tricks to fix this problem.

Here is the sample: 
https://jsfiddle.net/j17qtLfv/

I want to keep 2 or 3 col one row even small size.

Any one can help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, remove the class names that indicate that it should be a different column layout on smaller screens.

```css
.row {
  background: #f8f9fa;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.col {
  border: solid 1px #6c757d;
  padding: 10px;
}

#block{
  background:red;
  min-width:1000px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<!-- 
  Bootstrap docs: https://getbootstrap.com/docs
-->
<div id="block">

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-6">
      1 of 2
    </div>
    <div class="col-6">
      2 of 2
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-4">
      1 of 3
    </div>
    <div class="col-4">
      2 of 3
    </div>
    <div class="col-4">
      3 of 3
    </div>
  </div>  
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

This blog provides steps to disable responsiveness of bootstrap.

http://blog.netgloo.com/2014/05/11/how-to-use-twitter-bootstrap-3-for-non-responsive-site/